# How and in what classes is one taught proofs?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I am currently in 10th grade, but am taking calc 3 in a university. Unfortunately, I feel that my classes go over topics, but never apply serious proofs to them, which is really frustrating. My question is whether this is normal and the proofs behind various theorems are taught in later classes or whether it is on me to learn the proofs myself. Furthermore, I would like to read a book on real analysis which would give me some of the formal proofs that I didn't get in the class and have been looking at this book: [https://www.amazon.com/Elementary-Classical-Analysis-2nd-Edition/dp/0716721058/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_txt?ie=UTF8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0716721058)

Is it too difficult for someone just starting out in actual math(learning things intuitively with the occasional proof) or will it be conquerable with some persistence?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: I haven't used that book, but I feel like a good class in set theory and perhaps abstract algebra would be a good precursor to analysis. At least at my university, the first classes that tend to involve formal proofs are in set theory and number theory.

Comment: Some university offer a course specifically called "intro to proofs". Don't you have a undergrad advisor who can answer you this?

Comment: I learned how to do proofs from Spivak's Calculus. I can recommend it.

Comment: I second the recommendation to check out Spivak's book Calculus. It was written for this purpose. Abbot's book Understanding Analysis is also good: https://www.amazon.com/Understanding-Analysis-Undergraduate-Texts-Mathematics/dp/1493927116 You might also try reading a number theory textbook.

Comment: Thanks for all your feedback! The Spivak book seems perfect for my purposes at the moment. I will probably also get the abbot book as well, even if I just occasionally reference it for now, I'm sure I'll use it more as I improve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, in the US proofs are introduced in a class called "Discrete Mathematics". That class starts out with formal logic and goes through a bunch of proof techniques (direct, contrapositive, contradiction, induction, maybe more). I would describe that class as a gateway to the upper undergaduate (3000 and 4000 level) math classes. Then when you take a class such as Intro to Number Theory, Intro to Abstract Algebra, Intro to Real Analysis, etc., you pretty much start from the brginning of that subject and prove everything in class as you go along (and you will have some relatively easy proofs for homework).

Some years ago I was in perhaps a similar situation to yours; I had just finished calculus 3, and I was very excited to buy a real analysis book and start reading. However, I was highly unprepared. If you want to learn anaylsis right now, my advice to you is as follows: get a discrete math book and learn the logic chapter, the sets chapter, and the functions chapter at a minimum. Only then try for Real Analysis. I don't know what book to recommend for Discrete Math, but for Analysis I recommend "Understanding Analysis" by Stephen Abbott.

I also recommend that in addition to reading the books, you also watch video lectures on youtube from a university. Yes, you could learn much just from reading the book. But I think you will learn more (and faster) by listening to what specialists from the field, with decades of experience, have to say on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

At least for most students in the United States (although individual experiences surely vary), the first real exposure to theorem and proof comes in geometry.  The sort of deductive reasoning from a set of axioms or postulates, echoing that of Euclid's *Elements* (with modern formalizations of course), is a very accessible form of mathematical proof.

In fact, proofs across a variety of mathematics are introduced throughout one's mathematical education in high school.  The derivation of the quadratic formula, for instance, is a form of proof.  Trigonometric identities are also proofs.  And in calculus, the use of the delta-epsilon definition of limit is also a kind of proof, even if one does not discuss how more powerful theorems regarding limits arise from this definition.

So perhaps what distinguishes calculus from analysis is that the latter lays down the framework or foundations on which one performs the calculus.  And these ideas do involve a great deal of mathematical proof to establish.  But even here, there are different depths of what constitutes a "proof"--that is to say, you could think of the fundamental theorem of calculus in a narrow context as a statement about the Riemann integral and prove it in that context; or you could think about it as a much more general statement about integrals on manifolds in the form of Stokes' theorem.  Both are analysis, but clearly not on the same level of sophistication in the machinery involved.

For a student studying higher-level calculus, it is hardly conceivable that there should be proficiency at this computational level without having been at least exposed or familiarized with the mathematical thinking involved in elementary proofs.  Thus, I am less concerned about whether the shift from calculus to analysis can be made at such a stage of mathematical development, or the various prerequisites from other areas of mathematics (e.g. set theory or algebra), as I am about whether the aforementioned depth is suitable.  For instance, I would not hesitate to introduce such a student to Apostol's *Calculus*, or Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*.  These are fine texts (though not without their own drawbacks from a pedagogical perspective).  But I would not recommend a higher-level treatment.

If one is truly serious about learning mathematics--and such a statement naturally implies that proofs as opposed to computation be an essential aspect--then one should expect to use multiple sources and numerous texts across a variety of fields of study.  There is not simply one, or even a few, definitive texts about real analysis, no more than there is one source to learn about differential geometry, or algebraic number theory.  The literature is vast.  Therefore, do not worry too much about starting off with the "wrong" text.  If it is too easy, just get another one (though this is rare, as most students will know if it is too easy before buying it).  And if it is too hard, let it serve as motivation for when you will eventually grow into it.  One should also not expect to become well versed in all areas of mathematics.  A certain level of familiarity is certainly possible--and expected in degree programs--but beyond that, the corpus of research mathematics becomes quite impossibly large for any one individual to master.

Answer (score 0):

It depends widely upon the country and type of institution.  In many non-engineering focused American universities there is an entire "transition to proof" course; others may just go straight to them in Calculus I, at least for some students.

In any case, you can definitely learn how to prove and get better at proofs.  There are several good and quite introductory English-language books on introduction to proofs at the [American Institute of Math](https://aimath.org/textbooks/approved-textbooks/) website.